# What are the names for geometric arrangements like 'quincunx'?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

A **[quincunx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quincunx)** is a geometric pattern consisting of five points arranged in a cross:

[image]

This seems like a very specific name derived from the Latin root for five (*quin*). Are there other geometric arrangements with similar related names that were derived the same way, or is *quincunx* unique?

Comment: This really seems like a list request to me--could you possibly rewrite a bit?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "geometric arrangements". Are you also specifically looking only for Latin-based words and only mystic symbols?

Comment: I’ve found a few interesting ones to go with quincunx: semunce, sextile, semisextile, tetronkion, pentonkion, sequiquadrate.  There is also some connection with NAND I am still tracking down.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that *tetractys* should match this request.

> Tetractys is a triangular figure consisting of ten points arranged in four rows, which is the geometrical representation of the fourth triangular number.

Comment: Tetra- would make it of Greek origin while quin- is Latin. I'm not sure if the OP is particular about this. But it might be worth noting in your answer. Interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

“Similar related names that were derived the same way” is unfortunately ambiguous, but if you mean are there other geometric arrangements with names formed by prefixing a Latin geometric term with a Latin numeric prefix, the answer is yes.  For example, from etymonline, *[triangle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=triangle)* derived  “from O.Fr. *triangle* (13c.), from L. *triangulum* “triangle,” from neut. of adj. *triangulus* “three-cornered,” from *tri-* “three” (see *tri-*) + *angulus* “corner, angle”, and *[quadrangle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=quadrangle)*  “from O.Fr. *quadrangle* (13c.), from L.L. *quadrangulum* “four-sided figure,” properly neuter of Latin adjective *quadrangulus* “having four quarters,” from L. *quattuor* “four” (see four) + *angulus* “angle”.   *[Pentagon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pentagon&searchmode=none)* and *nonagon* also are from Latin.  However, *[pentangle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pentangle&searchmode=none)* and *[hexagon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hexagon&searchmode=none)* are from the Greek.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more precise. I am aware of the names of geometric *figures*. I was hoping to get names of geometric *arrangements*.

Comment: *Pentagon* looks Greek at both ends

Comment: @Henry, I agree, but the etymonline *[pentagon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pentagon&searchmode=none)* entry suggests it arrived in English via Latin.

Comment: @nohat, a geometric *arrangement* consists of lines (or hyperplanes), not of points.  Points form geometric *configurations*, not arrangements.  See sections 1.1 and 1.3 of Edelsbrunner's *Algorithms in  Combinatorial Geometry*.

Comment: I didn't mean any technical definition of "geometric arrangement"; I was just referring to the idea that a quincunx describes how five items might be arranged in a geometric pattern, such as dots on the side of a die, whereas a triangle describes a *shape*. I use these words in their lay meanings—the senses you would find in an ordinary dictionary.